# How to set protected routes with NextJS 13?

Tags: web, next.js, next-auth

I have been working on a website whose major component is a student and faculty login portal. Now, I have managed to generate a JWT and store it as a cookie in the browser and on successful student login, it takes you `/student`

However, if someone simply types `/student` into the URL, it still redirects. You can check out the full code down here:
https://github.com/shivpreet16/event-junction

I am not sure how to set `/student` as a protected route so as to make it inaccessible by simply typing in the URL. I tried to Chat GPT my way through this and wrote `/utils/withAuth` :

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { getTokenCookie, isAuthenticated } from './auth';

const withAuth = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const Auth = (props) => {
    const token = getTokenCookie();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isAuthenticated()) {
        Router.push('/');
      }
    }, []);

    if (!token) {
      return null;
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

And during export default in `/student.js`, I wrote:
`export default withAuth(student)`

However, this does not seem to recognize the withAuth function itself:

[image: Server Error]

Any idea how to work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to figure it out. We basically used `cookie-next` to store the JWT in the front end. Then, before pushing the protected route, we used a `useEffect()` . The code snippet looks like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!getCookie('student_cookie')){
        router.push('/')
    }
  }, [])
```

This code runs exactly once before the `/student` route gets displayed. It checks for the existence of the cookie and uses the email details in the cookie to get to the right information on the student page.

Answer (score 2):

I created a function that I call inside every server component that's supposed to be protected.

`protectedPage.tsx`:

```
import { cookies } from "next/dist/client/components/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function protectedPage() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessToken = cookieStore.get("accessToken");
  const refreshToken = cookieStore.get("refreshToken");

  if (!accessToken || !refreshToken) {
    return redirect("/auth/sign-in");
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
export default function Test() {
  protectedPage();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hello this is protected</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this only check whether or not an accessToken is present in the cookies? Wouldn't there also need to be a part where the accessToken is checked for its validity by the server?

Comment: The server should of course be checking the token, I just didn't include that in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing this in Next 13 is by using Nextjs 's Middleware. All you have to do is to just create a Middleware.ts file in the root and before each page request you can check if isAuthenticated() is true or not.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { isAuthenticated } from './auth';

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  const protectedRoutes = ["/", "Route1", "Route2"];

  if (path.startsWith("/_next")) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated() && protectedRoutes.includes(path)) {
    const httpsRedirectUrl = `${Your_URL}/login`;
    return NextResponse.redirect(httpsRedirectUrl);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```